# A simple Meetings CRUD (CREATE/READ/UPDATE/DELETE) PHP Application : Best Practice

Tags: php, database-design

In a PHP application i am developing, I would like to know which way of the following is a good approach to create a meeting based on availability.

**Option 1** - I am planing to keep predefined types of time slots such as, *8:00 am to 9:00 am (SLOT 1)*, *9:00 am to 10.00 am (SLOT 2)* and etc. in a separate table **called meeting_intervals**

**Option 2** - Letting a user to provide a **FROM** and **TO** time. i.e From 8:00 am to 9:30 pm. i feel this way its much more flexible.

Which of this can be useful in the long term plan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options are viable in my opinion, given that a user can book more than one slot at a time in option 1. Furthermore, if you decide for option 1 I suggest to use shorter intervals (maybe 15 minutes) so you can have flexibility and simplicity. 
What are you most concerned with?

Comment: Flexibility. its a meeting request by parents to teachers.  so school time is also a concern.

Comment: Given the context, to get the most flexibility you should definitely go for option 2. I suggest you use Timestamp type fields instead of integers as suggested by eXtreme, but apart from this I agree with him. To handle the school time, you can create a separate table with one field for the day of the week and two more fields for start and end time of the schooltime (e.g. Mon, 08:00, 13:00) so you can easily retrieve them and loop over them to check if the user is trying to book a valid interval. You can then create another table to create intervals of days to handle holidays periods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your idea but if I design the table I'll add two fields:

```
start INT(11) NOT NULL
end INT(11) NOT NULL
```

They will keep the date and time in [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) format. This variant is more flexible because you can specify date, hours, minutes and seconds instead only hours and minutes in your way. Also the select queries are easy to build.